Title of Saturday Kung Fu movie on TV I saw as a kid with hitting post and marble?
I saw a Kung Fu movie on TV on Saturday as a kid in the late 70s/80s that I enjoyed a lot. It's a long shot but was wondering if anyone knew the title. There is a list of all those type of Saturday Kung Fu movies on line but it's too long to have descriptions.
In the movie the main character is trying to avenge his parents death. When he confronts the villain using his father's kung fu technique, he is defeated. He is trained by an old man using a hitting post. I believe it is shaped like a person with horizontal poles attached. A marble is placed into the top of the hitting post and the hitter must do his technique but still be able to catch the marble as it comes out the bottom before it hits the floor.
After his defeat, he trains with the old man's advice and includes his mother's kung fu techniques in addition to his dad's.  Upon his next try, the villain expects to defeat him because the main character's moves are the same. However at the end the main character uses one his mother's kung fu techniques that the villain wasn't expecting and defeats him.
The movie has elements of the Kung Fu series of the old man/snatching the pebble and elements of Karate Kid with the one special move that defeats the opponent. Thanks for your time and possible help.

I saw this movie as a kid.  It was great (as far as I can remember).  I'm almost positive you are asking about Executioners from Shaolin
see: wikipedia entry
He is trained by an old man using a hitting post. I believe it is shaped like a person with horizontal poles attached. A marble is placed into the top of the hitting post and the hitter must do his technique but still be able to catch the marble as it comes out the bottom before it hits the floor.

trains with renewed zeal on a sophisticated life-size bronze dummy fitted with grooves representing acupuncture meridians along its surface. By releasing a vessel in the head, metal balls cascade along these grooves so that he can snatch them to train his speed and accuracy.

includes his mother's kung fu techniques in addition to his dad

Wen-Ding returns to avenge his father's death having been forced to synthesize his father's Tiger style with the crane style his mother taught him

Here is a screenshot of the father using the training dummy with the marbles:


On the larger question of "what film is this?", the answer is "an important piece of a greater body of work that spans nearly all of Kung Fu Cinema." 
Executioners from Shaolin may be the earliest collaboration between actor Gordon Liu and director Lau Kar-Leung, considered one of the all time greats.  It spawned a more famous sequel The 36th Chamber of Shaolin, now starring Liu and again directed by Lau. Liu would go on to become one of the biggest stars in Kung Fu movies. 
Note that this film involves the character Pai Mei, who was famously featured in the Quentin Tarantino masterpiece Kill Bill (see "The Cruel Tutelage of Pai Mei").  In the Tarantino film, Gordon Liu plays Pai Mei, a reversal of his adversarial role in Executioners.
Both Gordon Liu and Lau Kar-Leung are/were real martial arts practitioners, known for Tiger-Crane, which is used in this movie to defeat Pai Mei.  Lau's lineage comes directly from Wong Fei-Hung who is considered the father of modern Hung Gar, which includes Tiger-Crane style. (In fact, Lau's father, Lau Cham, played his own real-life Sifu, Lam Sai-Wing, in the 1950's era Wong Fei-Hung films starring Kwan Tak-Hing. Lam was one of Wong Fei-Hung's principle disciples, and this series was a predecessor of the Once Upon A Time in China series, most famously starring Jet Li.) "Hung" is a character in Executioners. 
These links demonstrate the influence of a real martial arts lineage on this area of Chinese cinema, both in terms of characters and action. Executioners represents a second major generation of technique, both in terms of choreography and action directing.    
Lau Kar-Leung was also a renowned choreographer (the "Lau Clan" was one of the early kung fu movie choreography families and extremely influential.) Lau choreographed such perennial favorites as One-Armed Swordsman and Master of the Flying Guillotine.  He also choreographed and directed Jackie Chan's Drunken Master II, known for the opening spear duel underneath a train. Jackie Chan, of course, plays Wong Fei-Hung in that series. 
Gordon Liu and Lau Kar-Leung collaborated on at least 18 films, including the classics Heroes of the East, Martial Club, and My Young Auntie, in which Liu displays his guitar-playing talent.
Unrelated note: I was lucky to have the chance to meet Gordon Liu. He is an incredibly cool and genuine person, extraordinarily kind to his fans--a real pussycat despite his badassery. Lau Kar-Leung, on the other hand, had a much fiercer reputation. Hong Kong legend holds that Lau walked in on his ex-wife and a lover, and the lover, rather than face the renowned Kung Fu master, jumped out a high-rise window to his death. (Yup, he was for real.;)

Um, what part of this post is supposed to be an actual answer to the question asked here? This all reads like a huge assessment of the situation of Kung Fu films and their influence, which is all nice and well, but not the slightest what was asked here. If any of the films listed here is actually supposed to be a real answer to the question at hande, then you might want to thin out a bit of the interesting but nevertheless superfluous ramblings and concentrate on that answer, preferably with some elaborations in which way this fits to the details of the question.

It might be the answer this question deserves, but it's not at all the one it actually needs. We're not a discussion forum here. Feel free to take a look at the [tour] and the [help] to get a better grip of how this site works. You seem to have some great insight into things and your contributions would be very welcome, but are better spent on questions that actually need them.

It's context.  Chinese Kung Fu Cinema is quite interesting. People with an interest in this movie may well be interested in this information, which includes links to related films. Also, it gives relevant information on the film's director and one of its stars.

Which movie? So is it only an elaboration on the movie from the other answer? In this case then yeah, as I said, interesting information, but this is just not what answers are for. As said, this is not a discussion forum here and if you don't have an answer to the actual question, I'm afraid this should rather have been a comment instead.

The Gordon Liu/Lau Kar-Leung link is quite relevant, so it's not merely an elaboration but a more detailed answer to "what film is this".  i.e. the film in question is not a monolith, but part of the central tradition of Chinese kung fu cinema, linked to both earlier and later films.  Possibly it should have been in the comments.

All the related films are in bold.  I'll link them once I get some rep. :)

"a more detailed answer to "what film is this". i.e. the film in question is not a monolith, but part of the central tradition of Chinese cinema, linked to both earlier and later films." - Feel free to flesh it out a little more into that direction then, to make this more apparent.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

How did an exploration of the importance of a film and genre end up trumping my actual answer?

Wasn't meant to trump it JohnSG.  You were excellent in providing the specific answer regarding the title!  (Hell, I voted for you;)
